# ORA-00936 with a substitution variable - error does not make sense

Tags: oracle

A super simple example of my script looks as follows:

```
-- Report Name: "Report_1"

col   letters   new_value   p_letters

SELECT letters
  FROM param_table
 WHERE report_name = 'Report_1';

CREATE TABLE temp_table_1
(letter varchar2(1));

INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE '&&p_letters' = '' OR letter IN (&&p_letters);
```

For some reason, our system has a table called param_table: users enter parameters through the UI, the parameters entered are written to param_table, and then my script pulls the user's parameters from param_table.

As far as I understand, the first SELECT statement selects the letters column from param_table and makes its values accessible in '&&p_letters'. In my INSERT INTO statement, when my WHERE clause looks like this...

```
WHERE letter IN (&&p_letters);
```

...and the user enters letters separated by single quotes, eg ('A', B', C'), the script runs fine. I want to make the parameter optional, so I adjusted the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE '&&p_letters' = '' OR letter IN (&&p_letters);
```

In my output file, I get the following error:

```
WHERE (('' = '') OR letter IN ())           *
ERROR at line ...:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

The compiler has evaluated the substitution variable correctly as '', but I'm getting an error.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA-00936 is because `IN ()` is not valid - you're missing something inside that. It is that it is complaining about, not the `'' = ''` part, though the result of that is undefined. You can check both conditions:

```
SQL> select * from dual where '' = '';

no rows selected

SQL> select * from dual where dummy in ();
select * from dual where dummy in ()
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

---

If you `set verify on` you can see how the substitution is handled. For your original query you'd see:

```
old:INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE letter IN (&&p_letters)
new:INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE letter IN ('A','B','C')

3 rows inserted.
```

You can see that the post-substitution statement looks, and is, valid.

With your modified query you'd see:

```
old:INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE '&&p_letters' = '' OR letter IN (&&p_letters)
new:INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE ''A','B','C'' = '' OR letter IN ('A','B','C')
```

which generates an ORA-00920 because of the messed-up single quotes in the first expression. With no value from `letters` you'd instead see:

```
old:INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE '&&p_letters' = '' OR letter IN (&&p_letters)
new:INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE '' = '' OR letter IN ()
```

which is the error you saw, ORA-00936.

I'd be tempted to do this with a collection type, either your own, or if you're comfortable with it then a built-in one:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table_1(letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(&&p_letters) IS EMPTY
    OR letter MEMBER OF SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(&&p_letters);
```

That works with your three comma-separated values, or null, since an empty collection is allowed. [Read more about `is empty` and `member of`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions006.htm).

It would be better, of course, to not store comma-separated lists in a single column value anyway, and to change your data model so this kind of manipulation and reliance on client behaviour isn't necessary.

Assuming you're stuck with the data model, you could at least avoid the client reliance buy tokenizing the string (I'm using one common approach below) and looking for matches. However, you also need to account for either the report name not being in the table at all or the report existing with no `letters` value, both of which are handled by the `max(letters) .. is null` check - which makes it a bit ugly.

It's all in one statement though, with no need for a separate query to get the parameters and no need for substitution variables. (And there may be better ways to do it!)

```
INSERT INTO temp_table_1 (letter)
SELECT DISTINCT letter
  FROM table_alphabet
 WHERE (
          SELECT MAX(letters)
            FROM param_table
           WHERE report_name = 'Report_2'
       ) IS NULL
    OR letter IN (
          SELECT TRIM(q'[']' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(letters, '[^,]', 1, LEVEL))
            FROM param_table
          WHERE report_name = 'Report_2'
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(letters, '[^,]', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
       );
```

Comment: Using the built-in collection type, a null value:

(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL())

did not cause an error, but no data was returned.

Comment: @Jake - sorry, was concentrating on not erroring, not what you said the end goal was. Updated the collection version.